# With UI-Router how can I do an action on change of state from parent to child?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have tried to use the *`onExit`* but the problem there is if I go from: `home` to `home.abc` or `home` to `home.def` then this does not trigger as a change of state when I put onExit in the `home` state.

Is there a way I can detect changing from `home` to `home.abc` or `home.def` or .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oz0JCfoEWVaDqaUGxYr1?p=preview)

We can use this piece of code, which on state change checks, if the next state name, does contain the previous state name *(which should be true, if next state is a child of previous)*

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, tparams, from, fparams) {

      var formChildToParent = from.name !== ""
        && to.name.indexOf(from.name) >= 0;

      if(formChildToParent)
      {
        alert("going from parent " + from.name + " to child " + to.name)
      }
    });
}])
```

That is just a light draft, which could be extended with more checks... but the concept should fit. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oz0JCfoEWVaDqaUGxYr1?p=preview)